# Describe a spring with newton's second law

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I explain or derive the differential equation 
$$y''(t)+y(t)=3\cos(kt)$$
with newton's second law.

The equation describes a spring. Can anyone give a hint?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Compare the given equation with $m\ddot{y}+sy=F_o\cos \omega t$
which shows the forced vibration without damping. one should get 
$$m=1, s=1, F_o=3, \omega=k$$

Where, $m$ is mass suspended from spring with stiffness $s$ & $F_o$ is the applied periodic force having angular frequency $\omega=k$

And $m\ddot y=1$ is the $\color{red}{\text{inertia force}}$ of mass $m$, $sy=1$ is the $\color{red}{\text{spring force}}$, & $3\cos (kt)$ is the $\color{red}{\text{periodic force}}$.

The given second order differential equation: $y''(t)+y(t)=3\cos(kt)$ can be solved for displacement $y(t)$ as a function of time $t$